# Exported JS files are different on two platforms OSX and Ubuntu

Tags: webpack

I'm developing JS application using webpack.
However, when our team uses the Ubuntu server to compile (webpack) the application. The generated files are having different files size as the MacOS local dev does.

What's the possible root cause?

- We invoke this command on the Ubuntu `./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js`

[image: inline]

## Webpack setting

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
...
externals: externalLibs, 
...
```

## Package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "@types/es6-shim": "^0.31.33",
    "@types/immutable": "^3.8.7",
    "@types/mathjs": "0.0.34",
    "@types/node-uuid": "0.0.28",
    "@types/react": "^15.0.25",
    "@types/react-dom": "^15.5.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "^4.4.40",
    "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.3",
    "node-uuid": "^1.4.8",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.1.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.5",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.1",
    "ts-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "ts-node": "^3.0.4",
    "typescript": "^2.3.4",
    "typings": "^2.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "webpack": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
  }
```

Comment: How do you call webpack? From CLI or as npm script, and with what parameters?

Comment: Hi, we simply use this on Ubuntu `./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js`

Comment: Without any parameters? So for dev I wouldn't take care about file size diff, but for production you should use `webpack -p`. Code will be minified and uglified. Here is an example to make it easier: Put in your _package.json_ the script  `"scripts" : {  
          "build:prod" : "webpack -p" }  
    }`
and then start building via `npm run build:prod`. You can add more run targets as you want, seperated by comma. Production releases should be the same size. If not, try to compare the releases with a diff tool.

Comment: Actually the file size diff does cause the behaviour inconsistent. It's so strange. Every macbook could reproduce the exactly same out files.

Comment: Are you using installing your dependencies including `webpack` using a [`package-lock.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json) file? Lock files will ensure the dependencies are resolved and installed exactly the same in both locations. Subtle differences in dependency versions could cause something like this.

However, it could just be the file system between the Ubuntu server and your macOS development environment are different. Therefore subtle differences in file size could occur because of things like allocation unit size.